# Does kafka consumer uses http request to poll or web sockets?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I understand how the consumer and producer works in kafka, but I am curious about some internal working of them.

How kafka consumer polls through kafka topic? Is it through http request or web sockets ?

Could you please explain in detail how does this mechanism work in kafka? For producer too.

And what is the advantage of using one over other in case of kafka(which is used for real time asynchronously consuming and producing)?

Answer (score 1):

Neither. Kafka has its own custom TCP protocol.

If you want to use HTTP requests, that's what the Kafka REST Proxy is for.